# ansible hash summ of vaiables

Tags: ansible, environment-variables, hash, templates

Help please, the second day can not solve the problem.
I need to add checksum sha1 in file that is created from a template
Example:
{{ item.some_var1 | hash('sha1') }} - work fine

But when I'm trying to get something like this
{{ item.some_var1 'some_string' | hash('sha1') }} - not work
{{ item.some_var1 item.some_var2 | hash('sha1') }} - not work

Documentation reading, but something I can not understand
[http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html#set-theory-фильтерс](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html#set-theory-%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81)
Please, help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you want to achieve, but probably this would help:

```
{{ (item.some_var1 + 'some_string' + item.some_var2) | hash('sha1') }}
```